# Ubuntu not starting and recovery not working

Tags: boot, 16.04, recovery-mode

When I try to start my Ubuntu I am getting the following error
[image]

When I tried to enter recovery mode I am not able to move my pointer to different options or select any one.

**How all this happened!!**

My PC had recently closed after a power failure but I was able to use my pc without any errors. But after using it once and shutting down I am unable to start my pc.

At first I was able to start to recovery mode and when I performed fsck check it was stuck so I pressed the restart button of CPU after which I unable to select anything in recovery.

Can anyone help me get my pc to start?

Comment: Since there is a problem with a USB device, have you tried to disconnect your USB devices? Or in the case the filesystem is broken, you might need to reinstall the OS.

Comment: @Melebius I have no USB devices connected to my PC other than mouse and keyboard so the problem might be due to filesystem. Is there any other way to repair the filesystem? Also will i lose my files in homefolder if I reinstall OS?

Answer (score 0):

Your Ubuntu installation seems to be broken according to your description of how did you get there. The easiest way to fix it could be reinstalling Ubuntu.

Before you proceed, make a backup of the filesystem (just in case, something bad can happen at any time). You can use command line within the Ubuntu Installer or the wizard with [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/).

Launch the Ubuntu installation. In the Installation type, choose Upgrade. After the installation completes, your refreshed Ubuntu should be there for you.

Sources:

- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuReinstallation
- https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=11770332

Comment: Will my files(eg home folder) and installed applications with their setting get removed when I upgrade? I remembered that I changed the /etc/fstab file in emergency mode and removed the options of root partition and changed them to default. Could that be the reason for the error?

Comment: @pcforgeek The [image of the installer](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Su5Ay.png) is pretty clear but nothing can be guaranteed with a broken filesystem… I strongly recommend to do a backup.